# xbbg gives "Cannot connect to Bloomberg" error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, finance, bloomberg

I recently started experimenting with [xbbg](https://pypi.org/project/xbbg/) on my mac, but the moment i try to run something simple (as shown below) I get a `"ConnectionError: Cannot connect to Bloomberg"`

```
from xbbg import blp

`blp.bdp('AAPL US Equity', flds=['Security_Name', 'Last_Price'])`
```

I am not running this from my terminal (obviously) and due to the current COVID situation i can only access my terminal from a browser, how can i connect it?

Thanks!

Comment: "I am not running this from my terminal" is the problem...

Comment: @assylias, right! which is why i'm wondering if anyone knows a way to connect with "bloomberg anywhere"

Comment: Install a Bloomberg terminal on your machine and it will work. Or remote into a machine that has the terminal installed and run your app on the remote machine.